# Need example for Boost UDP multicast server

Tags: c++, boost, timer, udp, multicast

I am following Boost's UDP Time server tutorial [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime6.html)
.  However, it is not what I want.  Is there any sample for a Boost multicast UDP server that sends out periodic message on timer event anywhere?  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, found it [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/multicast/sender.cpp)
.

Need to tweak a little bit with a new periodic function to be called by the class constructor:

```
void send_periodic()
{
    static int i = 0;

    std::ostringstream os;
    os << "Message " << message_count_++;
    //message_ = os.str();

    socket_.async_send_to(boost::asio::buffer(message_), endpoint_, [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
    {
        cout << i << endl;  // show request count
        ++i;
    });

    timer_.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    timer_.async_wait([this](boost::system::error_code ec)
    {
        send_periodic();
    });
}
```